# Changing Font For Entire App In Android

Tags: android, fonts

So i did some research first before asking this question because i know there are lots of article concerning this subject. 
But the solutions i found regarding changing the font of the entire application is limited to textview only and not to the actionbar and menu for example. i also know how to change the font of these too (in each activity) but this is done at run time so when i am using the below code for example to change the font of the menu items, i notice the texts change from default font to the custom font. 
my question is, is there a better way to do this

```
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainpage, menu);


        getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new Factory() {
            public View onCreateView(String name, Context context,
                                     AttributeSet attrs) {

                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("TextView")) {
                    try {
                        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                        final View view = li.createView(name, null, attrs);
                        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {

                                if(MainActivitySharedPref.GetValue(getApplicationContext(), "Language").equals("ar")) {
                                    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), getString(R.string.arabic_font_name));
                                    ((TextView) view).setTypeface(font);
                                    ((TextView) view).setTextSize(22);
                                }
                            }});
                        return view;
                    } catch (Exception e) {Log.e(TAG, "[ERROR] an InflateException was thrown: " + e.getMessage());}
                }
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Button")) {
                    try {
                        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                        final View view = li.createView(name, null, attrs);
                        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {

                                if(MainActivitySharedPref.GetValue(getApplicationContext(), "Language").equals("ar")) {
                                    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), getString(R.string.arabic_font_name));
                                    ((Button) view).setTypeface(font);
                                    ((Button) view).setTextSize(22);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        return view;
                    } catch (Exception e) { Log.e(TAG, "[ERROR] an InflateException was thrown: " + e.getMessage());}
                }
                return null;
            }

        });

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i got no answer i will post what i did to solve the issue of having the default font be loaded for milliseconds before the custom font appears. (in menu items ...)
i placed the code in OnCreate method and removed the run function.

```
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
        final LayoutInflater.Factory existingFactory = layoutInflater.getFactory();
        // use introspection to allow a new Factory to be set
        try {
            Field field = LayoutInflater.class.getDeclaredField("mFactorySet");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.setBoolean(layoutInflater, false);
            getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new LayoutInflater.Factory() {
                public View onCreateView(String name, Context context,
                                         AttributeSet attrs) {

                    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("TextView")) {
                        try {

                            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                            final View view = li.createView(name, null, attrs);
//                            new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
//                                public void run() {

                            if (MainActivitySharedPref.GetValue(getApplicationContext(), "Language").equals("ar")) {
                                Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), getString(R.string.arabic_font_name));

                                ((TextView) view).setTypeface(font);
                                ((TextView) view).setTextSize(22);
                            }
//                                }
//                            });
                            return view;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "[ERROR] an InflateException was thrown: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }

                    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Button")) {
                        try {
                            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                            final View view = li.createView(name, null, attrs);
//                            new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
//                                public void run() {
//                                    // set the text color
                            if (MainActivitySharedPref.GetValue(getApplicationContext(), "Language").equals("ar")) {
                                Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), getString(R.string.arabic_font_name));
                                ((Button) view).setTypeface(font);
                                ((Button) view).setTextSize(22);
                            }
//                                }
//                            });
                            return view;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "[ERROR] an InflateException was thrown: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                    return null;
                }

            });
        }catch(Exception e){}
```